# How to set 'commandPath' for CKFinder when integrated with CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckfinder

How can I change the commandPath property (CKFinder.config.connectorPath) for CKFinder when it's being created via CKEditor(4)?

The documentation for vanilla CKF+CKE integration says:

> At the moment the only supported configuration options in the config
>   object are: basePath, width and height, all other settings will not be
>   used.

So under '[Manual Integration](http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/Java/CKEditor_Integration)', it only seems to list options for specific function URLs, but not the URL for the [CKFinder init](http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Server_Side_Integration/The_Commands/Init).

CKFinder's 'init' command is going to the default:
`/lib/ckfinder/core/connector/java/connector.java?command=Init&type=Images`

instead of the where my un-integrated CKFinder instance (on another page -and works) goes to the proper URL:
`/ckfinder?command=Init&type=Images`

-Can this be done? In this environment, I cannot change the location of the CKFinder backend files.

Comment: Is there an event I can hook the property change onto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the property has proven to be impossible. I have since resorted to creating an alternate 'ckfinder.js' file, with the appropriate connectorPath string, and loading the alternate as needed.